# Does scrollTo() have a "behavior" attribute like window.scroll()?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, customer-community, scrolling

I'm scrolling the page if the current Customer Community User is not a 'Guest User', but the page movement is abrupt. Is there an attribute I can set on **scrollTo()** for more elegant page scrolling in lightning components (similar to **behavior** on **window.scroll**)?

My Current Code

```
scrollTo('custom', 600, 200);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`scrollTo(target, top, left)` isn't a valid set of parameters for `scrollTo`, so presumably you're using a custom function. The way you'd do this using just standard JavaScript/Lightning would look like this:

```
var target = component.find("target");
var element = target.getElement();
var rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
scrollTo({top: rect.top, behavior: "smooth"});
```

Comment: I actually wasn't able to find proper params for scrollTo(), wasn't aware that the they are contained in an object. I was able to use behavior parameter for my purposes - thank you.

Comment: It is taking me to the top of the Page, but I want to navigate on a particular pixel. That pixel is not static, It may be changed.

Comment: @RajatJaiswal It does work correctly, both in Aura and LWC. I suspect that you may getting tripped up with a weird getBoundingClientRect value, which is why you'd be scrolled to the top. Double-check your values.