# scrollTo on Salesforce 1

Tags: lightning-aura-components, salesforce1-app

I'm developing a component, that have to work both, on browser and on Salesforce 1.

I have to create a button that on tap/click should make the page scroll to the target element.

Reading online i found [scrollTo](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/228627/does-scrollto-have-a-behavior-attribute-like-window-scroll) example, which works on browsers/desktop, but doesn't work on S1.

**There is anyway to replicate the scrollTo functionality on S1?**

Here my example code

Component

```
<div  aura:id="target">
  <span  class="button" onclick="{!c.gototarget}" >
      Click Here
  </span>
  <div> content here </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.THIS .button {
    position: fixed;
    padding: .5rem;
    bottom: 100px;
    right: 30px;
    z-index: 99;
    background: #fafafa;
    background-color: rgb(221, 219, 218);
    border-color: rgb(221, 219, 218);
    width: auto;
}
```

Controller

```
({
    gototarget : function(component, event, helper){
        var target = component.find("target");  
        var element = target.getElement();
        var rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
        scrollTo({top: rect.top, behavior: "smooth"});  
    }
})
```

Comment: ui:scrollerWrapper and good luck